# XAMPP working, but can't read php

Tags: php, xampp

I've just set up my XAMPP and it works fine, opens `//localhost/dashboard` fine, and `phpinfo()` as well. When I try `//localhost/test.php` which is just

```
<?php
    echo "Hello world";
?>
```

but the page is blank, I run it as a web page from localhost, not as a file, most probably it's a problem in installation but I haven't tweaked anything, and everything is by default.

Answer (score -1):

Create a folder in htdocs like "test".

Then in test put index.php with a simple Echo 'Hello';

Then on your browser (make sure apache + mysql are running in control panel).

Visit this in your browser:

http://localhost/test/index.php

Comment: everything you said is running but code doesn't work